# JBoss Eclipselink not creating indexes in postgresql on create-tables / create-or-extend-tables

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, jboss, eclipselink

I am working on a maven project using JBoss and eclipselink and I have problems creating indexes (via JPA) in postgresql with a JBoss server.

The tables and indexes are getting created when the ddl-generation property is set to "drop-and-create-tables"

```
<property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="drop-and-create-tables"/>
```

But when i set this property to either "create-or-extend-tables" or "create-tables", the tables are getting created and updated, but my indexes are NOT.

```
<property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-or-extend-tables"/>
```

I have tried running the same code on a Glassfish server, and on a Glassfish, the indexes ARE GETTING CREATED. So the problem only occurs when I'm running a JBoss server (ultimately, I want my project to run on a JBoss server).

Here is my persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="Request_PU" transaction-type="JTA">
<provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
<jta-data-source>jdbc/gid_postges</jta-data-source>
<class>be.uclouvain.digit.request.models.LogRequest</class>
<class>be.uclouvain.digit.request.models.LogStatus</class>
<exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
<shared-cache-mode>NONE</shared-cache-mode>
<properties>
  <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINE"/>
  <property name="eclipselink.logging.level.sql" value="FINE"/>
  <property name="eclipselink.logging.parameters" value="true"/>
  <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-or-extend-tables"/>

  <property name="eclipselink.deploy-on-startup" value="true"/>
</properties>
```

And here is an Entity exemple

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Identity", schema = "digit")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "SEQ_Identity", sequenceName = "SEQ_Identity", schema = "digit", allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 500000)
@EntityListeners(IdentityListener.class)
@Index(columnNames = {"Lastname","Firstname"},name = "IdxName")
public class Identity implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "SEQ_Identity")
    @Index
    @Column(name = "Identity_Id")
    private BigInteger identityId;
    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 50)
    @Index
    @Column(name = "Lastname", nullable = false, length = 50)
    private String lastname;
    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 50)
    @Column(name = "Firstname", nullable = false, length = 50)
    private String firstname;

    ...
}
```

Comment: check what it is executing; it is likely trying to recreate an index that already exists and then assuming they are all there.  I believe EclipseLink handles the indexes and constraints separately from the tables, and is treating it as an all or nothing. File a bug/feature to have this fixed.  On Glassfish, they use EclipseLink to generate scripts, and then execute the scripts.  This might work better for you, as the indexes would then be created independently, one by one, and so all get a chance to be recreated.

Comment: So, I checked ... I deleted all indexes and try to recreate them, but it didn't do anything (didn't even try to make a DB transaction) (with JBoss). I'll file a bug and hope it get fixed soon. Thanks!

Comment: I don't know what you mean when you say you deleted and tried recreating indexes. What is the SQL EclipseLink is generating?

Comment: I've added this line to see the generated SQL:

<property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode" value="both"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.create-ddl-jdbc-file-name" value="createDDL_ddlGeneration_kernel.jdbc"/>

Here is the result : (see next comment)

Comment: CREATE TABLE digit.Identity ((deleting this or comment is too long))
CREATE INDEX idxname ON digit.identity (lastname, firstname)
CREATE INDEX IdxFirstname ON digit.Identity (Firstname)
CREATE INDEX IdxLastname ON digit.Identity (Lastname)
CREATE INDEX IdxId ON digit.Identity (Identity_Id)
CREATE SEQUENCE digit.SEQ_Identity START WITH 500000
CREATE SEQUENCE digit.SEQ_Identity START WITH 500000

Comment: So it doesn't generate the script to create the indexes, but for an unknown reason, doesn't do it :/

Comment: by "deleted and tried recreating indexes" i mean that i manually dropped  1 or 2 indexes and then strated my application again on JBoss to see if it would automatically recreate them. (another exemple is adding a new index in our entity with @Index). But it only create indexes when the ddl-generation is on "drop-and-create-tables"

Comment: I don't believe the Create-or-extend will generate a script file for the DB changes, so you need to check the logs generated to see what it executes on your database. I'm pretty sure it tries to create all indexes, and just stops trying on the first exception, so it is a lost cause if you are trying to update indexes, but things might have changed since I last investigated the feature.

Comment: This feature isn't recommended outside of Dev.. you might be able to live with using the feature to update the tables, have it output the script, and then have Eclipselink execute the creation script to create all indexes (which will create the missing ones). Or just live with missing indexes until you can safely drop and recreate the schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright so I've manage to work around the issue to fix the problem by simply create my tables with eclipselink and then, save the script and then execute that script as a check, so if the indexes were not created with the tables, they would then be created by running the script.

Not great, but it'll work while waiting for a better solution.

My new persistence.xml looks like this :

```
  <property name="eclipselink.logging.parameters" value="true"/>
  <property name="eclipselink.logging.level.sql" value="FINEST" />
  <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINEST" />
  <property name="eclipselink.logging.level.cache" value="FINEST" />

  <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables"/>

  <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.action" value="create" />
  <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.create-target" value="../../NetBeansProjects/digit/src/Digit-kernel/src/main/resources/createKernel.sql"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.drop-target" value="../../NetBeansProjects/digit/src/Digit-kernel/src/main/resources/dropKernel.sql"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.sql-load-script-source" value="createKernel.sql"/>
  <property name="eclipselink.deploy-on-startup" value="true"/>
```